# Xubuntu Running Slower than windows with constant freezing

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, xubuntu

So I switched my computer to Ubuntu after some issues with Windows, then switched the GUI to Xubuntu after I noticed Ubuntu and Unity were painfully slow.

I'm running an i5 with 8 gigs of ram and I still experience at least one full freeze (where I can't do anything and have to unplug) per week. REISUB does nothing and never has. The GPU is an onboard Intel and my Ubuntu version is 13.10. The only process that's ever really using memory/CPU is Virtualbox, and I've never seen it above 50% memory or 25% CPU. I have never had this issue with Windows.

I am constantly running Virtualbox because I still need Windows.

Any thoughts to prevent this annoying freezing?

Comment: You're going to have to give us something more to go on. What version of Ubuntu are you using? What is your graphics card? Which driver do you use with it? Do you have similar problems in Windows? Are any processes eating up your CPU?

Comment: GPU is an onboard Intel. Version is 13.10. Only process that's ever really using memory/CPU is Virtualbox, and I've never seen it above 50% memory or 25% CPU. No, never had this issue with Windows.

Comment: What hardware are you using? Brand; model; type info would be helpful. Not all hardware is that well supported through Ubuntu.
What issues did you have with your Windows system? Are they maybe similar? Did it also freez? Even seen computers boot (laptops), because they got to warm. After cleaning the ventilation, it worked properly again!

Comment: Lenovo Thinkcentre M72e. i5 Processor. As far as the memory, I don't remember, Corsair maybe? I didn't have problems with freezing on Windows, we were testing encryption and I switched so I wouldn't have to deal with the problems the encryption caused on some. And it seems like I only have this happen when Virtualbox is open, which ironically enough I have to be able to have running all the time.